# Floating point exception caused by assigning a value to variable of type double

Tags: c++, linux, exception, sigfpe

Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
xxx::init (this=0xbffe47fc, aa=0x0) at s.cc:1061
1061            price = 100.0;

I just try to compile and run the code without any modification on different linux machine RH5.6 32bit, and the owner of this application compile it on RH5.3 which has no issue.

gdb bt

B::init

b_init

B::B

A::A

main

Here is the code

```
class A : public B
{
A () : a_1(1)
{
    init()
}

void init();

int a_1;
};

class B
{
double price;

B() 
{
memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this);
b_init(this);
}

int b_init( B* b)
{
return b->init();
}

void init()
{
price = 100.0;
}
};

int main()
{
A a;
}
```

I looks very normal to me. Can anyone shed some lights on it? Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code. How is `init` getting called? What happened to `aStruct`?

Comment: Missing argument in init() ??
Although it might not be the exact cause of error.

Comment: Please post a real program.  I can get a similar error by doing this:`xxx *px; px->init();`

Comment: I posted more detailed sample code. If I insert double temp = 1.1 before price = 100.0, then this line will cause the FPE.

Answer (score 0):

This test code works fine for me.  There must be something else going on?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct teststruct
{
  int a;
  double b;
};

class test_class
{
public:
  void init( struct teststruct * );
  double getPrice();
private:
  double price;
};

void test_class::init( struct teststruct *test )
{
  price = 100.0;
}

double test_class::getPrice()
{
  return price;
}

int main ()
{
  struct teststruct a;
  test_class test;

  test.init(&a);
  cout << "Double " << test.getPrice() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
[hendric@Linux-Test-System ~]$ g++ doubletest.cpp 
[hendric@Linux-Test-System ~]$ ./a.out
Double 100
```

Comment: Thanks!　I've put the code into a simple test function and it works fine. But the issue of the real world application is still unsolved. Too many lines of codes there.